# SqlCommand.Parameters Property - why it can be followed by add method?

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
```

As I know, mosty we use "= " for property get or set value.Parameters as property, why it can be followed an add function?

Comment: you can also set the value at the same time: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intVar;`

Answer (score 3):

Because the `SqlCommand.Parameters` property returns a `collection` to which you can `Add` a `Parameter`. The `Add` method creates a `Parameter` object using the *parameters* you passed to `Add` and then adds that object to the underlying `Parameter` collection.